# How to create relation between single column from one table and multiple rows from second table?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have two tables: `Players` and `Characters`. Every `Player` can have max. 10 `Character`s. I'm looking for best way to create relation between those tables. I was planning to use Foreign Key to connect column `characters` in `Players` with `id` from `Characters`, but I don't know if I should create 10 columns in `Players` like `character1`, `character2`, `character3`, etc. for each his character?

I know I can create column which will have value of type `integer[]`, but what about relation then?

I hope my question is quite clear, because I don't know how could I explain it better.

Comment: Why not a separate mapping table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely create two tables, one for Players and one for Characters. The Players table will use either a separate player_id column or a player_name column as the primary key. If you choose to have a separate player_id column, make sure you set the player_name as unique. The Characters table will have a character_id column, a player_id or a player_name column (depending on how Players is structured) which is a foreign key reference to the Players table and finally a character_name column. Each character will now represent its own row in the Characters table.

Comment: Yes, forgot about the restriction to max 10 characters. That should be done from the application code by querying the characters table and seeing the player already has 10 or more characters (in theory they should never have more though).

Answer (score 3):

Your foreign key should be on the characters table - referencing the player_id. There is no way to restrict this to 10 in the constraint - you will have to either code for this of do a check in a procedure call to createCharacter which will perform the check for you.